# Why are the tab label widths started to squish when their respective content panels have more than 32 characters?

Tags: css, tabs, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm using daisyUI's [radio tab lifted + tab content](https://daisyui.com/components/tab/#radio-tab-lifted--tab-content). The code is the same with the demo, except the I only use 2 tabs and fill content to them:

```html
<div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-lifted">
  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 1 is very long" />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6"></div>

  <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 2 is very very long" checked />
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6">
    1111 2222 3333 4444 5555 6666 77
  </div>
</div>
```

([Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/w2yLdDwWd0?size=274x227))

At 32 characters, the tab label widths behave as expected: they fill all the horizontal space:

[image]

Starting from 32, they squish a little bit:

[image]

Each addition character squishes the width more. It reaches its minimum at 53 characters:

[image]

If we start again, but this time we use no space, then the maximum length is 7 before it start squishing:

[image]

The width reaches its minimum when the character length uses up the available horizontal space:

[image]

The squish only takes effect on its respective tab. The other one is intact.

Why does this happen? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent that by setting `grid-column` of the tab panel to the amount of tabs you have:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/daisyui/4.6.1/full.css" integrity="sha512-XpYSkIPzmQpbWTGbLUWq0HyRQ5n9RZFeH8TrfqIykNiE8OXQLn207Am0aU4nVplNE8vvJ1qCY6JvD9weUAyosQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="w-[274px]">
  <div role="tablist" class="tabs tabs-lifted">
    <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 1 is very long" />
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6"></div>

    <input type="radio" name="my_tabs_2" role="tab" class="tab" aria-label="Tab 2 is very very long" checked />
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-content bg-base-100 border-base-300 rounded-box p-6 !col-span-2">
      11112222333344445555666677
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for why it happens, the `.tab-content` has:

```css
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: span 9999;
```

At the small width of 274px, the content of the `.tab-content` becomes significant and affects the width of these other 9997 grid column tracks that the `.tab-content` spans, shrinking the grid column tracks that the tab labels reside.

Comment: adding `col-span-2` on both tabs fix the issue. I wonder why you need to wrap them inside `<div class="w-[274px]">`? Also, if the tab name text needs to be on multiple line, can you make the tab height adjust to that as well?

Comment: I wrapped them inside `<div class="w-[274px]">` to emulate your Tailwind Play where you had the viewport at 274px width. You can make the tab height adjust for when the tab name text needs to be on multiple lines.